# Manually installed TexLive on Fedora 16

Tags: installing, texlive, texmaker

I manually installed TexLive on Fedora 16 because I need to use `tlmgr` and install some packages. Now I want to get Texmaker, which I installed with `yum`, to work with the manually installed TexLive rather than the automatically installed one.

How can I configure it to do that?

Comment: TUG gives some answers to install correctly a vanilla TeXLive  http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html for Debian and Ubuntu users and I think it's perhaps the same things with Fedora.

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Thanks, I was not aware that self-answers are acceptable. On some Stackexchange sites, you need high level of reputation to answer your own questions.

Comment: @xiongtx: That's news to me. Usually there is just a time delay so you can't ask, answer and accept a post in short regression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.

Go to `Options -> Configure Texmaker` and replace `latex` with `/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/latex` or equivalent. Do the same for `pdflatex`. Everything else should be fine, although I have not done further testing besides compiling some old documents.