# Fedora manual installation and dependencies

Tags: installing, texlive, linux, r, dependencies

Following answers on this website (like: [How to use TeX Live on Fedora 17?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59953/how-to-use-tex-live-on-fedora-17) and [Manually installed TexLive on Fedora 16](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52187/manually-installed-texlive-on-fedora-16) )
I installed texlive manually on fedora and it works flawlessly.

The problem I have is that tex is a requisite for other packages (such as R). Whenever I try to install (through yum) R i am required to install another tex  from fedora.

 I don't want to do so because the package is old, it doesn't have tlmgr and I don't want to have two installed tex.

Is there a way to make the OS notice I already have tex installed and the dependency is satisfied? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While option 2 from the question in [How to use TeX Live on Fedora 17?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59953/how-to-use-tex-live-on-fedora-17) will solve this problem, you're probably trying to get around deficiencies in [jnovy's TexLive repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/TeXLive).  You want `yum` to think you have the proper packages installed, but it seems to go against `yum`'s policy to provide a way to fake dependencies.  You could try using [a fake TexLive RPM spec file](http://osdir.com/ml/fedora-users/2011-04/msg00309.html) or [fakeprovide](https://github.com/larsks/fakeprovide).

Sample [fake RPM spec file](http://osdir.com/ml/fedora-users/2011-04/msg00309.html) from the link:

```
Name: texlive2010-fake
Version: 1.0
Release: 1%{?dist}
Summary: This is a fake TeXLive package
Group: Applications/Publishing
License: GPLv2 and BSD and Public Domain and LGPLv2+ and GPLv2+ and LPPL
BuildRoot: %(mktemp -ud %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-XXXXXX)

Provides: config(texlive)
Provides: kpathsea libkpathsea.so.4()
Provides: tetex tetex-dvips tetex-fonts tetex-latex tex
Provides: tex(dvips) tex(latex) tex(tex) tex-preview texinfo-tex
Provides: texlive texlive-afm texlive-context texlive-doc texlive-doc-errata
Provides: texlive-dvips texlive-dviutils texlive-east-asian texlive-fonts
Provides: texlive-texmf texlive-latex texlive-utils texlive-xetex
Provides: texlive-texmf-afm texlive-texmf-context texlive-texmf-doc texlive-texmf-dvips
Provides: texlive-texmf-errata texlive-texmf-errata-afm texlive-texmf-errata-context
Provides: texlive-texmf-errata-doc texlive-texmf-errata-dvips texlive-texmf-errata-east-asian
Provides: texlive-texmf-errata-fonts texlive-texmf-errata-latex texlive-texmf-errata-xetex
Provides: texlive-texmf-fonts texlive-texmf-latex texlive-texmf-xetex


%description
This was necessary to have a tlmgr-based installation of texlive and all the
rpm packages that requires texlive (e.g., a2ps and R-core) still installable.

%prep

%build

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%doc

%changelog
```

To install:

1. `rpmdev-setuptree` (as a normal user) to create the necessary ~/rpmbuild tree
2. `rpmbuild -bb --clean texlive2010-fake.spec` to create the RPM
3. `yum install --nogpgcheck texlive2010-fake-1.0-1.fc17.x86_64.rpm` to install the RPM

Answer (score 4):

I'm running also Fedora.

What I have done was:

1. Installation of a minimal tetex system using yum (so that the other dependencies are met)
2. Installation of TexLive in /opt/texlive
3. Configure PATH and ?TEX? variables to use /opt/texlive... (add the /opt/texlive/.../bin to be before /usr/bin, so that the Texlive executable are found first

Comment: That's what I used to do but for some strange reason some packages (in particular pgf) would be always read from the fedora texlive and that was a big issue for me.
Maybe I didn't change the TEX environment variable correctly? How is it done properly?