# Install IDE without installing TexLive 2007

Tags: installing, texlive, kile, dependencies

I've been trying so hard to make TexLive work on my Fedora, but I can't find a way. I've installed TeXLive 2012, but when I install Kile, it says it depends texlive2007, the old version. Then I tried to install TeXStudio, but it also depends of texlive2007.

How can I install it without installing the old version? I'm using Fedora 17.

Comment: when you [TeX.SX search](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=fedora+17+texlive) you find [Fedora manual installation and dependencies](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87030). I think you need a dummy/fake rpm to fool the IDE while installation

Comment: it didn't work for me. i couldn't generate the fake rpm package.

Comment: Your best bet is to install TL2012 manually to e.g. `/opt` _and_ let Fedora install its TL2007. Then adjust the paths so that you really use _your_ TL2012.

Comment: I've done that, Martin. I set TexLive 2012 path before the original path, like this: export PATH=/opt/texlive/bin/x86_64:$PATH, and it worked. Thanks for the comments, a sorry for the duplicated question